# Next.js : getStaticProps with context API

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-context

I'm currently building my first next app (e-commerce with Shopify Storefront API).

In order to avoid multiple query to the db and upgrade performance, I want to store all datas once a user sees a page:

1- first loading (by page): the method `getStaticProps` fetch the necessary datas and put everything in a context `ShopContext`

2- when the user hits the page another time: instead of `getStaticProps` re-fetch the datas, just use the data in the context.

Is it something logical to do that? And if yes, is it possible to avoid data fetching when a loading page occurs?

Many thanks for your responses ! :)

Comment: You already get that behaviour with `getStaticProps` out-of-the-box. With `getStaticProps` Next.js will pre-render your pages at build-time.

Comment: @juliomalves thx for your response! that's mean at the first render, the datas are loaded and on the other render, the datas are already loaded?

Comment: It means the pages will get pre-rendered when you build the app, before someone even accesses the page.